# Your branch and 'origin/yourbranch' have diverged keep local files

Tags: php, git, github, version-control

I have this diverge branch issue. In many of these cases you want to throw away your local changes. But in this case I'm really happy with my local files.

So basically what I want to do is to replace everything with my current local files. I would even like to replace my master branch. How do i do this?

Here is the error message:

```
Your branch and 'origin/yourbranch' have diverged,
and have 4 and 7 different commits each, respectively.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for you to abandon the old changes:

1. Diverged local branch with repo branch. As you have diverged local yourbranch and origin/yourbranch, you can force to keep origin/yourbranch same as the local yourbranch by `git push -f origin yourbranch`.
2. If you really want to abandon every changes in yourbranch, you can make an orphan branch (no parent commit id) from it by `git checkout --orphan yourbranch1`.

The ways can also apply to master, you just need to delete master branch (`git branch -D master`) and then rename a branch to master (`git branch -m oldname master`).